# Android KeyStore GUI

Tags: android, keystore

I'm looking for a GUI to help create and manage keystores for Android development.

The tool should be able to modify the KeyStore files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/) is a popular option if you don't want to use the terminal/command line.

Answer (score 2):

[KeyStore Explorer](http://keystore-explorer.org/) is a very popular and well maintained (as of Feb 2018) GUI keytool. The best part is that it's [open source](https://github.com/kaikramer/keystore-explorer). Read more about it on their [website](http://keystore-explorer.org/index.html)

> ### KeyStore Explorer
>
> KeyStore Explorer is an open source GUI replacement for the Java command-line utilities keytool and jarsigner. KeyStore Explorer presents their functionality, and more, via an intuitive graphical user interface.